# Why I need to add gnome ppa to upgrade/update my Gnome Shell version, when I'm using Ubuntu Gnome?

Tags: gnome, upgrade

I have Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 and I was searching to upgrade gnome shell from 3.16.4 to 3.18.
Because of this nice features from [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/09/gnome-3-18-release-new-features).
Every place in the internet that I found said that I must to add a PPA repository like [“GNOME3 Team” team](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3) to be available to update / upgrade the gnome shell.

My questions are:

1. This is True / False?
2. If yes, why do I need a PPA if I have already installed Gnome Shell?
3. Which PPA is the most Stable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true.  Ubuntu 15.10 was released with Gnome 3.16, and Gnome 3.18 will not be officially available until Ubuntu 16.04

There are two gnome sites on Launchpad:

if you `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` then you can `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and will be at gnome 3.18.  There is also a repository `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging` which brings in more of the Gnome 3 packages, but it not quite stable.

Please note that both sites recommend that you use `ppa-purge` to remove their packages before you to a distribution update!

Comment: First at all, Thanks,
second, How did You know or where You found that Gnome 3.18 will not be support in Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: @Aby I'm not sure where I found out, it was several months ago.  The Gnome release cycles and the Ubuntu release cycles to not coincide, and when Gnome 3.18 was released, Ubuntu 15.10 had already frozen the packages for the release.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is True / False?

This is true.

2. If yes, why do I need a PPA if I have already installed Gnome Shell?

Because Gnome 3.18 is not in the repositories. 3.18 is not 100% compatible with 3.16, and so they don't want to release it as an update. Instead,

3. Which PPA is the most Stable?

Well you don't have a PPA for 3.16, so this is a non question. If you are asking which one you should use? I'd advise you stick with 3.16. 3.18 is not a revolutionary change, and as I said before, it may not work perfectyl on 15.10.

Wait a few months for 16.04 to be released (in April 2016). I'm looking forward to it too!